# CSS Media Query min-width not working correctly

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a HTML like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Code: NewYork</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>
<body data-ng-app="us">
    <input type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS is:

```
input {
  background-color: red;
}
/* ---- Desktop */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    input {
        background-color: green;
    } 
}
```

now the CSS applies when the window is at 909px width. Obviously not a scrollbar problem. I am getting nuts with this simple problem. I tested it with Chrome and IE10 both the same.

Can anybody please help what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I used this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Code: NewYork</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="us">
    <input type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

With a simpler media query declaration like this one:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1200px) {

 input {
        background-color: green;
    } 

}
```

It's working great here: http://jsbin.com/ubehoy/1

Debugging with [Firefox Responsive Design View](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View) and dragging the resizer, it changes the input background color correctly when the width limits are reached.

Tried with Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m/IE 10 and it's working great too.

Comment: you are right, for any strange reason my chrome measures 900pixel though window is 1000 pixels. though html and css are exactly the same. i opened a window put both documents in two tabs to ensure that width is the same. in my local document chrome measures 900px :(

Comment: Damn i was stupid. that tab was at zoom level spent hours on this -_- i should work so late... thanks!

Comment: :D... this is a difficult thing to look at, really!

Comment: big upvote for @user1974505 I had the same stupid zoom at 110%. As soon as I read it I did a /facepalm and reset to default... works like a charm!

Comment: Me too, and it turns out there is a magnifying glass in the address bar when not at 100% - I fail.

Comment: THANK YOU! I will NEVER make this mistake again. I went as far as to determine it was working at a pixel amount 10% to late... I did the calculations and didn't realize I was at 90% zoom :/ I tested in 2 other browsers and I somehow managed to do the same thing...

Comment: I had the exact same problem. And yes, the magnifier was on! Didn't know that would affect the reported pixel width of the page.

Comment: Just had the same problem and my magnifier was on too.. thanks so much for this or I would have never caught it.

Comment: Magnifier fail for me too... :(

Comment: Just have to check in and say that zooming was really wrecking me and I'm sure I wouldn't have seen this on my own, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I have had this happen to me from time to time. Make sure your tab is not zoomed in (⌘0)

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1200px) {

 input {
        background-color: green;
    } 

}
```

This works, but make sure you check the zooming. (I got this answer from the comments, as it seems this is the big catch around here.. I fell for it too)