# Media query is not applied at the required min-width

Tags: css

I have made very simple example on media query but I am surprised that its effect is not applied at the exact `min-width` but it is applied at (offset + `min-width`)

HTML doc is just empty

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test media query</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
</head>

 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
body{
background-color: grey;
}

@media (min-width: 500px){
body{
    background-color: red;
}
}
```

So background colour of body should be changed once the window size on my PC reached 500px but I found that it is changed once it reached 875px on Google Chrome?

How can I force it to change once it reached 500px as I just wrote in my code?

Comment: You can add 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
and in css if want put @media screen and (min-width: 500px)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Media Query min-width not working correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681054/css-media-query-min-width-not-working-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is that I was zooming in my webpage :)