# How to do media queries without affecting other media queries

Tags: css

I am a bit confused here... I found some common breakpoints to use for my css media query but am only using max-width such as @media screen and (max-width: 812px) {} etc but it seems to be moving my other media queries around. I thought that this should only affect the code that is 812px or less. Do I need to add both a min-width and max-width to solve the issue ?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 50em) and (orientation: portrait) {
label {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;


}

.nav {
  width: 200%;

}

#nav-icon {
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 1em;
  color:  #ffffff;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

div.nav ul, div.nav li, label{
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 2em;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 150%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: .9em;

}

div.header2_welcome h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5em;
  left: 0em !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}





img.pc101 {
  width: 20em;
  height: 7em;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 27em;
 margin-left: -15em;
  font-size: .8em;

}



div.natural {
  font-size: 150px;
  position: relative;
  right: .5em;
  top: 2em;
  animation: drop 2s ease forwards;
  margin-bottom: 1em;

}

div.flat {
  font-size: 150px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1200px;
  bottom: 450px;
  top: 8em;
}

div.treble_clef {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: relative;
  right: 400px;
  bottom: 400px;

}

div.crotchet_rest {
  font-size: 6em;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 800px;
}

div.crotchet {
  font-size: 6em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3.5em !important;
  top: 3em;
  animation: drop 2s ease forwards;
}

div.minim {
  font-size: 6em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1.5em;
  top: 2em;
  animation: drop 2s ease forwards;

}
```

}

This is only a sample of my code but don't know it is moving my other media queries around..

Comment: Could you share a sample code ? 

And I think that, you could use both of them :

Check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681054/css-media-query-min-width-not-working-correctly

If this is not about your question, please share a sample code.

Comment: max-width:812px means from 0 to 812px

Comment: add code for better understanding

Comment: I have also used a lot of !important... will that make it confusing because without it, I can't move things around

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will help you.

```
<style>
  @media only screen and (max-width:768px) and (min-width:200px)
  {
     /* Your CSS Code */
  }
</style>
```

Comment: So from my understanding, a max-width of 812px should only affect any device with 0 - 812pixel and not my 1024 pixel?

Comment: Yes, For making more responsive you write different media queries for different size or device.

Comment: maybe I have done something wrong with my ipad portrait because in the chrome extension, it says that the width is 768px by 1024 so in my query, should i type max-width 768 or 1024?

Comment: I am also confused here because when I change my media query from 812px to 518px, it seems to be ok.... I am wondering why I can't do a media query for the iphone x?

Comment: this is strange... I thought that the max-width for an iphone is 812 but it is also 518... I can even move the iphone x with a max-width of 518

Comment: Is there a problem with using the 812px?

Comment: We can use different media queries for different device widths if you use according to 812px the design represents according to only 812 px. And if you check on different device width which doesn't have of 812 px then it may not be responsive as you want. So you have to use different media queries for design, which makes your design best.

Answer (score 0):

The media query may have a lots of condition

- only for screen of less than 500px
  `@media only screen and (max-width:500px)`
- only for screen between 200px and 500px
  `@media only screen and (min-width:200px) and (max-width:500px)`
- only for screen more than 500px
  `@media only screen and (min-width:500px)`
- only for screen on every size
  `@media only screen`
- only for print on every size
  `@media only print`
- only for sqare screen
  `@media (aspect-ratio: 1/1)`
- only for sqare screen
  `@media (aspect-ratio: 1/1)`
- only for screen of aspect ratio superior to : 16/9
  `@media (-max-aspect-ratio: 16/9)`

ecc..  you can specify pixel-ratio or dpi to better fit your need